# How can i manage download and print in visual basic 10 webkit browser?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, printing, download-manager

I created a webkit webbrowser in visual studio 10(visual basic) for running a specific web app . The issues started when am trying to print a webpage by clicking a link in the website. when clicking on the link i want show the default printer dialoge or printer preview dialoge of that document. And the second problem is i want to add a download manager for my browser.
please help me to overcome this problem. can anyone send the source code for this or a demo projct in visual basic 10.

thanks in advance

Comment: please include the code you've tried so far and tell us where you're stuck

Comment: @WimOmbelets Actually am a beginner in visual basic 10. The web browser created using webkit-cairo dll for avoiding JavaScript errors. I just tested my browser with some urls. But i want to show print preview or print dialog when i am clicking on the link (link to print some thing in the webpage) present in the website.

Comment: 'Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If My.Computer.Network.IsAvailable Then

            WebKitBrowser1.Navigate("http://domain.com")
        Else
            MsgBox("Please check your internet connection", MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel)
        End If
        'Beforehand store as many downloadable file types as possible in an ArrayList object
        
    End Sub

End Class'

Comment: Please don't post extended code fragments in comment. If you feel it's a relevant part of the question, edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @WimOmbelets , i want to show print preview dialoge on the basis of link url. and i dont know how its possible in my webkitbrowser

Comment: @WimOmbelets : do u know how to build aperfect browser. that support javascript, jquery, and no css errors

Comment: I hope that's a rhetorical question... so no, I don't. Why?